# Splitting numbers from letters

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a column that contains values such as:

```
7D  
13M  
24D  
55D
```

I want to split the values into a group of the digits and another with the letter so I can further evaluate.

I am pretty close using the built in regex with this function

```
def string_split(type: str):
  res = re.findall(('\d+'), type)
  
  if ["d"] in res:
    return "days"
  if ["m"] in res:
    return "months"
```

right now my `re.findall` is only returning the digits and not the letters.

Comment: Why would you expect it to return letters? `\d+` only matches numbers.

Comment: Is the last character always going to be a letter?

Comment: Are your strings only in the format of numbers-then-D-or-M? It would be overkill to use regex for that and you could simply do `numbers, letter = int(s[:-1]), s[-1]`

Comment: Consider `\d+[md]`. This has the added benefit of only matching if you have a character and a digit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `re.findall()`. Your strings are always a number followed by a letter. So use a regular expression that matches just that pattern, rather than splitting it.

```
def string_split(type: str):
    m = re.match('(\d+)([A-Z])', type)
    if m:
        num = m.group(1)
        unit = m.group(2)
        if unit == 'D':
            return num, 'days'
        elif unit == 'M':
            return num, 'months'
        else:
            raise ValueError('Invalid unit ' + unit)
    else:
        raise ValueError('Invalid interval ' + type)
```

Comment: Hi, @Barmar,  Mino `typo`?  Should be  - if unit `==`  'D'

Comment: Yes, even experienced programmers aren't immune to that error.